# Angular *ngIf directive on component doesn't save value (Ionic 3)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, angular5

I created angular components on Ionic 3. 
and I created several div tabs using *ngIf directive. 
Now I can switch between tabs using buttons..

However, when I navigate to other section of main html page which is containing that component, *ngIf directive seems to lose its current value. It defaults back to its original tab. 
This is a problem for me. I'm trying to make ngIf directive tab stay at where they are.. 
How can I accomplish this? should I store ngIf's value to local storage? is there any other way?

Main HTML page seems to store ngIf directive value as long as ngIf is not nested within a component.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: No solutions found yet... please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a service that holds a state variable of which tab is active

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class TabService {


  tabState: number = 0;

  constructor() { }


  setTab(index: number) {
    this.tabState = index;
  }

  getTab() {
    return this.tabState;
  }
}
```

Then in your component, inject service, and on init, get tab

```
  currentValue = 0;

  constructor(private tabService: TabService ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.currentValue = this.tabService.getTab();
  }

  currentValueChange(currentValue){
    this.currentValue = currentValue;
    this.tabService.currentValueChange(currentValue);
  }
```

Note, don't forget to inject service as a provider

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! I have tried it and it's not working.

Comment: So, my main HTML page has two tabs. and the component nested inside one of the tabs has four tabs. I created service and imported properly but no luck... is it possible for you to show me a simple github example? thanks a lot!

Comment: Specifically, the example you have provided is working but ngOnInit seems to be trying to get tabState on initial start of my app and at initial stage, there's no numeric value loaded to tabState so it doesn't display anything. How can I load tabState numeric value later on?

Comment: You can initialize the value in service too.

Comment: Thanks, I posted a reply here.. yes, maybe I can use ngOnInit on service provider!

Comment: @jamesharvey, updated answer to reflect your newly shared code

Comment: THANK YOU! you totally made my day! It's working..  greatly appreciated!